# Telerik MVC Grid Refresh with jQuery Function

Tags: jquery, model-view-controller, telerik, grid, refresh

Hi I have a two MVC Telerik Grids Showing up in one View.

Each Grid has a Custom Column with Edit Link

When User Clicks Edit Link a dialog-model will popup with a form and after user hits save button.
Below Script will run

```
 function OpenStopForm() {

    $("#dialog:ui-dialog").dialog("destroy");
    $("#dialog-model").dialog({
        height: 220,
        width: 340,
        modal: true,
        buttons: {
            "Save": function () {
                var note = $('textarea[name=StopNote]').val();
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "/Medication/StopMedication",
                    data: { ID: pid, StopNote: note },
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: refreshGrid()
                });
                $(this).dialog("close");
            },
            Cancel: function () {
                $(this).dialog("close");
            }
        }
    });

}
```

after above function successfully runs,
I want the Two telerik Grids to refresh with some sort of ajax call.
i though of calling a function like this 
**success: refreshGrid**

```
function refreshGrid() {
     $('#CurrentMedication').data('t-grid').ajaxRequest();
}
```

But refreshGrid function is being called before my Controller action is performed.
I want this function to be called after my controller action is complete.

I am not sure if my syntax is correct!.

I tried to do something from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5565250/javascript-code-to-refresh-page-and-or-telerik-grid)

Can any one help me how to call the refreshgrid function upon success on ajax Post.
Also please correct me with my function to refresh the grid.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I have modified my ajax call as below

```
  $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/Medication/StopMedication",
                data: { ID: pid, StopNote: note },
                dataType: "text",
                success: function (data) {
                refreshGrid();
                }
          })
```

My refresh Grid goes like this

```
function refreshGrid() {
$(".t-grid .t-refresh").trigger('click');
}
```

Comment: the telerik grid has the option to let you put a refresh button at the top and bottom. If you have both enabled, then you will get two refresh calls per grid. I have only one grid, but needed this functionality and solved it by using the first object found: $(".t-grid .t-refresh").first().trigger('click'); This way the grid will get refreshed once instead of twice. However, if you have two grids (as OP does) then you would have to further qualify the selector. This answer was a key to getting my page running though. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If some one looking for this, there is a small change refresh should be called like

```
$(".k-grid .k-pager-refresh").trigger('click');
```